# getting GDB working with eclipse and the RX62N board from renesas

Tags: eclipse, embedded, gdb

I have set up the board according to the RX cpu example in eclipse, and everything seemed to be working fine till I wanted to get the example running on the board. When I click the option to hardware debug, I get an error saying "Error launching GDB server. Check installation".

Am I to re install eclipse, or the GCC toolchain for the RX cpu, or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about your specifics (that is Renesas or the RX62N). I do use eclipse for embedded work. Typically on a new platform I would make sure I can build and download a release version first. Once you have that working then see if you can get a Debug build and the debugger running. On the platforms I am used to, you have to put in hooks (typically just a single call) to enable the debugger. For exmple on the [NetBurner](http://www.netburner.com) the debugger can run over the serial port or Ethernet so the call has to specify which version you want to use. I know other platforms use JTAG debuggers etc, Typically a dev kit for the board comes with a manual that details how to get the debugger working. I doubt that you need to reinstall anything you just need to get the configuration set up correctly.